# Stub for google calendar API when using rspec in ROR3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

The following is the method I am trying to use for getting the API to make the calls to Google calendar. I am not sure what the stub should return. Should I capture the normal response and use it as is or is there a reference with minimum set of parameters?

```
api = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')

result = client.execute!(:api_method => api.calendar_list.list)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "reference with a minimum set of parameters"?  Rspec has a stub_chain (see http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Mocks/Methods/stub_chain) and the ability to place constraints on stub parameters which would let you implement whatever you want, I would think.

Comment: Instead of capturing the entire response from the server and using it as the mock's response, I am looking if there is an option in google_client_api to stub with minimum params like Omniauth provides.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that Omniauth provides it's own [mock support](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing) and I can see that Google provides [Python mock libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/mocks), but I'm not aware of any direct Google support for mocking from Ruby.

That said, given your example, you would need test doubles for client and api. It's not clear where client is coming from, but assuming that's established as a double somehow, you'd have at a minimum:

```
api = double('api')
client.should_receive(:discovered_api).and_return(api)
api.stub_chain(:calendar_list, :list)
client.should_receive(:execute!).and_return(... whatever result you want ...)
```

If in addition you want to confirm that your code is passing the right parameters to the Google API, then you'd need to augment the above with [message expectations](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#message-expectations) and, in the case of the api stub_chain, a return value which would then have to feed into the message expectations for the execute! call.

I'm still not sure that answers your question, but if not, I'll look forward to reading any additional comments.

Comment: I handled this case by capturing the response and storing it in a file and using it to stub the expected response for the call.

Comment: @karsep5 can you please provide an example of how you stubbed the request?

Comment: i actually captured the response and set it as the body using stub_request.